# Delegate delegated ipv6-net to another server

Tags: routing, dhcp, ipv6

i am trying to set up ipv6 for our internal net, so i configured our public ipv6 net for our dmz at first. Every host in the dmz has its own public ipv6-address now.

Since i have a 2-tier-firewall, i delegated an ipv6-subnet from our 1-tier-router to the 2-tier-router.

I don't know, if this is best practice, but now i want to assign ipv6-addresses from the global ipv6-subnet, that is delegated to the 2-tier-router of the internal net to hosts in the internal net. Since i am new to ipv6, i am not shure, if this is a good practice or if i should build up a random ipv6-subnet for the internal net (any suggests?).

Since the delegation is working as expected, assigning ips from the global ipv6-subnet to internal hosts should be no problem - but my 2-tier-router is not my dhcp6-host. In the internal net, i have a samba 4 dc, that serves ip-addresses via dhcp. The 2-tier-router is only used as the internet-gateway.
So now i am looking for a way, to delegate the delegated subnet (or maybe a sub-subnet) to the internal dhcp6-server of the dc.

Maybe i am thinking too complicated, but i think, it would be great, if the dynamically delegated ipv6-subnet would be dynamically delegated to the interal dc. Am i right or is there a more common way to handle with ipv6?

The 2-tier-router is a turris omnia that runs with a modified version of openwrt, so the configuration works with standard linux-tools.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Hendrik

Comment: Almost all host OSes today use privacy extensions and random addressing, changing the assigned addresses on a regular basis. The router RAs would need to be set up to override that for a DHCP server.

Comment: So i need RA between my dc and the 2-tier-router to exchange the delegated ipv6-prefix?

Comment: No. Routers send out RAs, and there are some flags in the RAs that tell the hosts how they should configure themselves. For example, the router will tell the hosts to auto-configure or use a DHCP server. IPv6 DHCP is _not_ like IPv4 DHCP. The router RAs tell the hosts which device to use as the gateway on the link. IPv6 interfaces can have multiple addresses of different or the same types on each interface, but the RAs will always be sourced from the router link-local address, with a list of prefixes for which it is a router. You should look at RFC 4861.